# BASH Script - Delete folders older than X days except for some and all their subfolders/files

Tags: bash, directory, except

I'm actually testing this script

```
find /Path/Folder/* -type d -mtime +7 ! -path "/Path/Folder/NODELETE1/*"  ! -path "/Path/Folder/NODELETE2/*"  ! -path "/Path/Folder/NODELETE3/*" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

to delete all files/folders older than 7 days except for `NODELETE1`, `NODELETE2` and `NODELETE3` folders.

The issue is that it apparently doesn't work, because of it deletes these folders and all files inside.

This is what I want to do:

I have

```
/Path/Folder/NODELETE1/some files and folders
/Path/Folder/NODELETE2/some files and folders
/Path/Folder/NODELETE3/some files and folders
/Path/Folder/AFOLDER/somefiles and folders
/Path/Folder/ANOTHERFOLDER/somefiles and folders
/Path/Folder/...
/Path/Folder/FILE
/Path/Folder/ANOTHERFILE
/Path/Folder/...
```

I want to delete automatically all files and folders older that 7 days (so `FOLDER`, `ANOTHERFOLDER`, `...`, `FILE`, `ANOTHERFILE`, `...`) so that

```
/Path/Folder/NODELETE1/some files and folders
/Path/Folder/NODELETE2/some files and folders
/Path/Folder/NODELETE3/some files and folders
```

What's wrong with the script?

EDIT with the script suggestion:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r -d '' dir
do

    # This line actually halts the control from entering if 
    # dirname contains either of the three names below. You could
    # remove it and put your actual folder names.

    [[ $dir =~ ^(NODELETE1|NODELETE2|NODELETE3)$ ]] && continue

    # Suggest un-commenting the echo line below and comment rm to ensure
    # you have only the folders you want to delete. 
    echo "$dir"

    # rm -rf "$dir"     
done< <(find /Users/Username/Desktop/test/* -type d -mtime +7 -print0)
```

For testing, I have:

```
/Users/Username/Desktop/test/NODELETE1
/Users/Username/Desktop/test/NODELETE2
/Users/Username/Desktop/test/NODELETE3
/Users/Username/Desktop/test/YESDELETE
```

and the script path

```
/Users/Username/Desktop/TEST.sh
```

Comment: Can you try  `-not -path "/Path/Folder/NODELETE1/*"` instead of  `! -path "/Path/Folder/NODELETE1/*"`

Comment: Only me suffering from paranoia and would never execute the `rm -rf` directly as an argument of `find -exec`? :)

Comment: @jm666: Same here, thats why suggested an alternate with proper name check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR Fix:

Instead of your line, do:

```
find /Path/Folder/* -type d -mtime +7 ! -path "/Path/Folder/NODELETE1"  ! -path "/Path/Folder/NODELETE2"  ! -path "/Path/Folder/NODELETE3" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Longer explanation:

The **-type d** part of your line searches for Directories only. But what you're excluding, are things inside your NODELETE directories. This still means that your NODELETE directories are targets for **rm -rf** and due to that they get recursively deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of relying on the core utils of the `find` command, I would suggest let `bash` take care of it ( you have tagged `bash` anyway) to exclude folders having the specific names,

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r -d '' dir
do

    # This line actually halts the control from entering if 
    # dirname contains either of the three names below. You could
    # remove it and put your actual folder names.

    [[ $dir =~ ^(NODELETE1|NODELETE2|NODELETE3)$ ]] && continue

    # Suggest un-commenting the echo line below and comment rm to ensure
    # you have only the folders you want to delete. 
    # echo "$dir"

    rm -rf "$dir"     
done< <(find /Path/Folder/* -type d -mtime +7 -print0)
```

Comment: It gives me this error `line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `<'` `/Users/Username/Desktop/TEST.sh : line 17:` `done< <(find /Users/Username/Desktop/test/* -type d -mtime +7 -print0)'`

Comment: @DylanDog: Are you running it with bash interpreter set? `#!/bin/bash` at top of script?

Comment: @DylanDog: Can you try with my update, `||` is replaced with `&&`, it was a mistake previously!

Comment: @DylanDog: Can you also post the complete script in the question? including my logic, it will be easy to point out the problem

Comment: @DylanDog: it is running perfectly fine for me!. Are you copy pasting stuff from Windows machine?

Comment: @DylanDog: Can you see which `bash` version are you using, do `bash --version`?,Also do `which bash` and add the path shown for `bash` in the header after `#!`

Comment: GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)

Comment: and yes the path is /bin/bash

Comment: I'll check what I'm doing wrong and I'll report here my error. If I could flag more then one answer as the best I would do it willingly. Your answer is certainly the best solution but for now I flagged the answer below as the solution. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @DylanDog: Happy to be of help, have no idea why the same is not working for you.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the ! as

```
 \! -path
```

to be sure it will not interpreted as pattern